# How does the Frobenius work on the Torsionpoints of an ellitptic curve with CM

Tags: elliptic-curves, class-field-theory, complex-multiplication

I am trying to understand the main theorem ov CM for elliptic curves. I work with the version stated in the second chapter of Silvermans "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetics of Elliptic Curves". 
I would like to make an example or something what illustrates clearly the statement.

Edit: What I did up to now is:

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $E: y^2 = x^3 +x$. I computed the m-torsion points for $m=1,2,3,4$. Now I want to see how the Gaolisgroup act an this points. And then check that there is a Frobenius who acts the same. 
I don't konw a lot about this Frobenius. How con I get it or describe it?

Comment: This is not very useful for those of us without a copy of the book to hand. Could you please give us the statement of the theorem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I wrote what I understand of this theorem, but I'm not sure how $K^{ab}$ comes into play

Comment: Cox, Primes of the form $x^2 + Ny^2$.

Comment: About the Frobenius in $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$ : if $\mu$ is a group endomorphism $E \to E$ then it is also a rational map $E \to E$, which defines a natural inclusion of field $\hat{\mu}:\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mu(E))\to \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}(E)$. You can then understand $\ker(\mu)$ and $ E/\mu(E)$ in term of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}(E)/\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mu(E))$. If this extension is separable then $\#  \ker(\mu) = [\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}(E):  \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mu(E))] =\deg(\mu)$. Take $\phi(x,y)=(x^p,y^p)$ the Frobenius, then $\# E(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}) = \deg(\phi^n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a long comment :

- Take an imaginary quadratic field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ and a fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a} \in K$, ie. $\mathfrak{a} = \lambda(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ for some $\lambda,\tau \in K$. Look at the complex torus $\mathbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}$. Note its torsion subgroup is $K/\mathfrak{a}$.
- Take a sequence $b_n \in \mathcal{O}_K$, for example $b_n = \prod_{c \in \mathcal{O}_K} c^{\lfloor n/N(c)\rfloor}$ such that $$K = \bigcup_n \frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{b_n}, \qquad K/\mathfrak{a}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{b_n}/\mathfrak{a}$$
  where the last limit is understood in term of inclusion of finite subgroups of the complex torus.
- Note for any $s \in \mathcal{O}_K$ then $z \mapsto sz$ is an endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}$ and $K/\mathfrak{a}$. And if $s=\frac{u}{v} \in K, u,v \in \mathcal{O}_K$ then $z \mapsto sz$ is an homomorphism $K/\mathfrak{a} \to K/v^{-1}\mathfrak{a}$.
- For a sequence $s_m \in K$, you can then ask whenever $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$ defines an homomorphism $K/\mathfrak{a} \to K/v^{-1}\mathfrak{a}$ for some $v \in K$.
  The answer is : when $s_m$ stabilizes modulo $b_n$ for every $n$, ie. when it stabilizes modulo $\mathfrak{p}^k$ for every prime ideal power $\mathfrak{p}^k$, ie. when $\lim_{m \to \infty} s_m$ converges as an idele of $K$.
- The main theorem of complex multiplication says that (using the Weierstrass function $\wp(z)$) such an homormorphism on the complex torus side has an elliptic curve counterpart $E(\mathbb{C}) \to E^\sigma(\mathbb{C})$ for some $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Thanks. Have to think about it

Comment: @anama The theorem is (much) more than that, so take it as a motivation why they introduce ideles in the thing. An example would to try $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$, see how $p$-adic numbers act on $K/\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and construct $\sigma$.